# Talkback not reading EditText Content Description

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility

The edittext can hold a max of 3 numbers and I want the TalkBack to read the numbers individually. The problem is that what ever I put in the contentDescription of the edittext, TalkBack ignores it and just reads the contents of the edittext, in this case, it always reads the number in whole instead of individually.

How can I make TalkBack read the numbers?